# pcl_visualizer.cpp vs 2015 build error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, point-cloud-library

When trying to compile PCL on a windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2015 i get the following error while pcl_visualizer.cpp is building

```
'static_cast': cannot convert from 'double' to 'pcl::visualization::LookUpTableRepresentationProperties
```

the corresponding line of code is

```
if (!pcl::visualization::getColormapLUT (static_cast<LookUpTableRepresentationProperties>(value), table))
    break;
```

Initially I thought this was an error of shared instead of static VTK libraries but rebuilding static libs resulted in the same error.

Has anyone encountered the same error and figured out the cause?

This might be relevant

[github merge log](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1634)

changing all

```
static_cast<LookUpTableRepresentationProperties>(value)
```

to

```
static_cast<LookUpTableRepresentationProperties>(int(value))
```

as suggested by the github merge logs prevented the specific errors from pcl_visualizer.cpp but running a full now

Answer (score 0):

This was a PCL bug and the fix was included in PCL 1.8.1.